# What is the right way to have a unique field that is 5 characters long for a Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

What I want to do is for each of my objects of a Model, there will be a unique label. This label will be a random string of 5 characters, made up of letters and numbers. Always generating a unique one could be a challenge. Right now, I am doing it the following way:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.label or self.label == '' or self.label == None:
            label = ''
            for i in range(5):
                label += random.choice(string.lowercase + string.uppercase + string.digits)
            if Order.objects.filter(label=label).exists():
                self.save() # Try again
            else:
                self.label = label
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Basically, the save method generates a label, and if the label matches with an existing object's one, the method is restarted. However, due to the nature of the randomness, it is almost impossible to test this. Will this way work? Or will I run into problems later on?

Also, please don't suggest UUID or something, as the label needs to be short and readable. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just try to add an `Order` object that doesn't conform to those standards and see what happens?

Comment: Why not just generate them sequentially from a numerical ID, considering the label as a "number" in base 62?  Also, you will definitely run into problems if you ever get 916,132,832 elements in your table, since then you will run out of unique labels.

Comment: I think the gotcha is the `super.save` call at the bottom -- if there's a collision, this will be called multiple times (possibly with different args) which may have interesting side-effects.

Comment: @BrenBarn If my product ever gets 916,132,832 orders, I will have bigger things to worry about. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do something similar for generating an 8 length unique value for `short_id` in a ShortLink model.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.short_id is None:
        self.short_id = self._generate_random_shortid()

@classmethod
def _generate_random_shortid(cls):
    length = 8
    char = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase

    # short_id must be unique
    while True:
        short_id = ''.join(random.choice(char) for x in range(length))
        try:
            ShortLink.objects.get(short_id=short_id)
        except ShortLink.DoesNotExist:
            return short_id
```